# What is the difference between final, const and static variables in java

Tags: java, variables, static, constants, final

What is the difference between final, const and static variables in java
with code example please 
`

Comment: This is very basic, you can find it everywhere on internet.

Comment: @mr.icetea 

yes i actually did google them but i got confused when gathered all information with each other so i asked for a code example so as to make it as clear as possible ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class X
{
  static int s; // can be accessed as X.s without object
  final int f = 7; // can't be assigned a different value
  const int c; // doesn't compile
}
```